# Dynamically Add and Save buttons in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic, android-button

Currently i managed to create the buttons dynamically on a view

Here is the my code to create the buttons;

```
    public void Add_on(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mb.this);
        View mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_mb1, null);
        EditText number = (EditText) mview.findViewById(R.id.etnum);
        Button Create = (Button) mview.findViewById(R.id.etcreate);
        Button Cancel = (Button) mview.findViewById(R.id.etcancel);

        Create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                if (!number.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Mb.this, "Number can be NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    LinearLayout yenilayout = new LinearLayout(Mb.this);
                    int n =1;
                    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                    {
                        Button yeniButton = new Button(Mb.this);
                        yenilayout.addView(yeniButton);

                        yeniButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(Mb.this, "Button is working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    altlayout.addView(yenilayout);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Mb.this, "Number cannot be NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
```

But whenever i recall the activity, the buttons are no longer exist. So May i know can i place the button there permanently?

Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Each time the activity is recreated, you will have to click on that `Create` button, to get those dynamic buttons.
PS: its a standard to use lowercase first letter for variables and uppercase first letter for Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Bundle` to save an activity's state and recreate it in the `onCreate()` method. This works for a particular instance of `Activity`, so can be used to save data concerning selection, or user input etc., but **not** data that you need to be persistent across application launches.

To use the `Bundle`, override the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` methods in the `Activity` class. You can use methods from [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to save whatever data you like in a map, and get it back in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`, which is called in `onStart()`.

The default implementations already handle most UI stuff though, and I would have thought this would keep track of your buttons for you, so it may be that your question is actually about associating some persistent data with your **application**. (this also means that if you do override the above methods, you should make sure to call the super methods in the first line of your implementation).

If you need persistent data across application launches, then the quickest and easiest way would be to use `SharedPreferences`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) answer for an example.